# Why do we need a servlet name?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have been readin *Head First JSP and Servlet*, I see that the `web.xml` has

```
  <!-- To name the servlet -->
  <servlet>                                    
    <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>packy.FirstServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <!-- For URL's to map to the correct servlet -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ServletURL</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Why hide the original servlet's location ? I can simply see that it is for security reason and some more such kinda advantages, but ***why have a name for each servlet*** ? Why can't the `web.xml` be simple like

```
  <servlet>                                    
    <url-pattern>ServletURL</url-pattern>
    <servlet-class>packy.FirstServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
```

Comment: A single servlet can have multiple mappings, in your suggested syntax each mapping would have a seperate servlet instance. Next to that what if you want to have multiple instances of the same servlet, with different settings?!

Comment: A typical usecase is that you can use * to match anything, so you can do do:  <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern> to match all requests for things in the /images directory to a single servlet. Usefull if you need image scaling, or image access control.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It allows you to have multiple servlet mappings on a single servlet instance (even spread over multiple `web.xml`/`web-fragment.xml` files) without the unnecessary need to create a separate instance per mapping:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>someServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.SomeServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>someServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/enroll</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>someServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pay</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>someServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/bill</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

*(note: yes, you can have multiple URL patterns per mapping, but that wouldn't cover them being split over multiple `web.xml`/`web-fragment.xml` files)*

It allows you to map filters on the particular servlet without worrying about what URL patterns the servlet is/would be using:

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>someFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>someServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Your proposal would support neither of them.

Note that since Servlet 3.0, which is out for almost 4 years already (December 2009; please make sure that you learn the matters by up to date resources ... anything older than 1~3 years should be carefully reviewed), you can easily use the `@WebServlet` annotation to minimze `web.xml` boilerplate:

```
@WebServlet("/servletURL")
public class SomeServlet extends HttpServlet {}
```

Just solely this annotation already maps it on an URL pattern of `/servletURL` without any `web.xml` entry.

Answer (score 4):

We don't really need a servlet name. It's just that this is how the Java EE designers chose to declare and map servlets in XML.

Nowadays, you can declare and map a servlet using the [`@WebServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) annotation, and the  `name` attribute of this annotation is optional.

Comment: I think this is more to the point. Another case of 'its just the way it is'!