# What is "addMappingForServletNames()" meant for when registering a filter?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, servlet-filters

In the `AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer`, I see the following logic:

[image]

What is the highlighted `addMappingForServletNames()` meant for?
What's the scenario this method should be used? I also see some people just call the `ServletContext.addFilter()` and do nothing else.

### ADD 1

Some quote from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-writing-filters.htm):

> Filters are defined and then mapped to a URL or Servlet, in much the
>   same way as Servlet is defined and then mapped to a URL pattern...You
>   can specify a particular servlet path if you want to apply filter on
>   few servlets only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`FilterRegistration#addMappingForServletNames()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/FilterRegistration.html#addMappingForServletNames-java.util.EnumSet-boolean-java.lang.String...-) does the same as below in `web.xml`:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>someFilterName</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>someServletName</servlet-name>
    <!-- <dispatcher>REQUEST|FORWARD|ERROR</dispatcher> --> <!-- If any -->
</filter-mapping>
```

In other words, it maps a filter on a specific servlet rather than a specific URL pattern. It will always be invoked when the specific servlet is about to be invoked. So it's basically listening on the same URL pattern(s) as that servlet.

Do note that this is not related to Spring, but just Servlet API specific.

#### See also:

- [Why do we need a servlet name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073905/why-do-we-need-a-servlet-name/)