# Map ServletRequestListener to Special Servlet

Tags: servlets, gwt

I have a several servlets and in my case I need to implement ServletRequestListener.  But, I don't want the listener to react on every request in any servlet.  I would like to know if there any possibility to map a specific ServletRequestListener to a specific certain servlet.  My web.xml looks like:

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CommonsServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.promptlink.dslib.gwt.common.server.rpc.CommonsServletImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
...
<listener>
        <listener-class>
            com.promptlink.dslib.gwt.common.server.httpListeners.ServletRequestListenerImpl
        </listener-class>
  </listener>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible with a `ServletRequestListener`. A servlet request listener listens on **every** servlet request. Just create a `Filter` instead which you can simply map directly to servlet name (no, not to its URL pattern, that's maintenance unfriendly).

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CommonFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.CommonFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CommonFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>CommonsServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

#### See also:

- [Our servlet filters wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info)
- [Why do we need a servlet name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073905/why-do-we-need-a-servlet-name/)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to react on the requests of a specific servlet then the servlet itself would be the ideal place to do this.

If you don't control the servlet code you can write a `Filter` and give it the same URL pattern as the servlet or directly refer to the servlet in the filter mapping.